# Ray-Triangle Intersection Detection using Barycentric Coordinates

Tags: java, collision-detection, graphics, raytracing, barycentric-coordinates

I am attempting to convert the algorithm from http://www.cbloom.com/3d/techdocs/fast_ray_tri.txt to java code, but my solution does not function correctly.

The only intentional change I made was for the second point, my method accepts a unit vector instead of the other end of the line segment.

For now, all collision calculations are done in this one method (nothing is pre-calculated).

Any suggestions as to what I may have done wrong?

```
//collision with barycentric coordinates
boolean checkCollision(Vector3f rayStart, Vector3f rayDirection){

    Vector3f normal=new Vector3f().cross(new Vector3f(point1).sub(point0), new Vector3f(point2).sub(point0)).normalize();

    planeOffset=-normal.dot(point0);

    Vector3f 
    edge1 = new Vector3f(point1).sub(point0),
    edge2 = new Vector3f(point2).sub(point1),
    edgePerp1 = new Vector3f().cross(normal, edge1),
    edgePerp2 = new Vector3f().cross(normal, edge2);

    float edgePlaneDist1 = edgePerp1.dot(point0),
                edgePlaneDist2 = edgePerp2.dot(point1);

    {
        float distance1=edgePerp1.dot(point2)-edgePlaneDist1;
        float distance2=edgePerp2.dot(point0)-edgePlaneDist2;

        edgePlaneDist1/=distance1;
        edgePlaneDist2/=distance2;

        edgePerp1.scale(1/distance1);
        edgePerp2.scale(1/distance2);
    }

    //point-plane distance
    float dFm=normal.dot(rayStart)-planeOffset;

    Vector3f rayEnd=new Vector3f(rayStart).add(new Vector3f(rayDirection).scale(30));

    float dTo=normal.dot(rayEnd)-planeOffset;

    float denom=dTo-dFm;

    Vector3f temp=new Vector3f(rayStart).scale(dTo).add(rayEnd.scale(dFm));

    float uTimesDenom = edgePerp1.dot(temp) - edgePlaneDist1 * denom;

    if ( uTimesDenom < 0 || uTimesDenom > denom )
    {
        // off triangle
        return false;
    }

    float vTimesDenom = edgePerp2.dot(temp) - edgePlaneDist2 * denom;

    if ( vTimesDenom < 0 || (uTimesDenom+vTimesDenom) > denom )
    {
        // off triangle
        return false;
    }

    return true;
```

Comment: it's hard to spot out of the first look the problem here , so it would really help if you can simplify the code and provide input data that is mathematically correct but the code fails to compute.

Comment: I don't have time to debug your code, but this is something that is commonly done by many people. Perhaps you can take a look at some reference code someone else has written, and then double check your math? Many people learn this from Ericson's book Real-Time Collision Detection.